# How to save uploaded image using Primefaces without database?

Tags: image, primefaces, save, managed-bean

I'm working on student registration form on Java web. I'd like to save uploaded image using Primefaces component and then display image in web page. The problem is that I will not use any database to store image.

So how can I code in managed bean because I couldn't understand how to do step by step?

Comment: You will require to write the images on your drive.

Comment: Hi, questions like these are way to broad. And effectively there are multiple Q/A related to this already on stackoverflow. If these do not help, ask your professor

Answer (score 0):

You may store the uploaded file into your physical machine, and if you do not want to use the db, you may store the path and filename into some flat file or xml file. This will help you in retrieving the image for further use in your project.